# Looking for SSRS filter which is identical to the SQL "IN" clause

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am attempting to set a conditional format for one of the fields in my SSRS report. Basic formatting which would change font color. This is my original expression in report builder:

```
=IIf(Fields!delta.Value <
            IIf("ex1"=Fields!ID_name.Value
                ,0.95
                    ,IIf("ex2"=Fields!ID_name.Value
                        ,0.988
                        ,0
                    )
                )
,"Red"
,"Black")
```

However, I have to do this for over a 100 different "ID_name" values which all share common "delta" values.

I was wondering if there is something similar to the IN clause in SQL that would allow me to paste all the "ID_name" values inside ('','','') format so it would be much easier? Something like this:

```
=IIf(Fields!delta.Value <
    IIF(Fields!ID_name.Value IN ('ex1','ex2','ex3','...')
        ,0.95
            ,IIF(Fields!ID_name.Value IN ('ex4','ex5','ex6','...')
                ,0.988
                ,0
                )
                )
,"Red"
,"Black")
```

I tried the IIf(InStr() method but my "ID_name" share similar names with others that have different delta values so a contains clause would not work.

Is this possible? Appreciate any and all input! Thanks!!

Comment: The ID names i.e. ex1, ex2, etc, are these accessible in SQL? Because you could approach this problem using a parameterised DataSet or a DataSet and Lookup function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but you'll need to wrap your text values in some kind of delimiter that won;t appear in your values to check like `[ex1][ex2]` etc..

You can use the contains method but it needs to be opposite way you would do a typical IN statement. Something like this..

```
IIF ("[ex1][ex2][ex3]".Contains("[" & Fields!ID_name.Value & "]"), 0.95, FalseBitHere)
```

Of course you can just use a comma or whatever you like as long as it wont; appear in your actual values to test.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Really appreciate it. I decided to just add another column using CASE WHEN to group "ID_name" with their "delta". It was just the easier / faster option